# How to align text and picture on top of table?

Tags: tables

I have a simple latex picture I want to align with the text. Here is a sample of code.

```
\begin{tabular}{ p{10em} p{20em} }

 \includegraphics{images/jouer.png}
 &
 Prevailed sincerity behaviour to so do principle mr. As departure at no propriety zealously my. On dear rent if girl view. First on
 smart there he sense. Earnestly enjoyment her you resources. Brother chamber ten old against. Mr be cottage so related minuter is.
 Delicate say and blessing ladyship exertion few margaret. Delight herself welcome against smiling its for. Suspected discovery by he
 affection household of principle perfectly he. \\

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

you need to move image baseline to izs top. This can be done for example with use of the `valign` macro from the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo,   % in real document remove "ddemo"
            export]{adjustbox} % it also load `graphicx` package

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ p{10em} p{20em} }
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{images/jouer.png}
 &
 Prevailed sincerity behaviour to so do principle mr. As departure at no propriety zealously my. On dear rent if girl view. First on
 smart there he sense. Earnestly enjoyment her you resources. Brother chamber ten old against. Mr be cottage so related minuter is.
 Delicate say and blessing ladyship exertion few margaret. Delight herself welcome against smiling its for. Suspected discovery by he
 affection household of principle perfectly he. 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```